How to calculate transition times for Sine-wave generation with a 2-bit DAC
I have a circuit I'm using to generate a sine wave. It consists of a 2-bit DAC (R-2R) folllowed by a Sallen-Key low pass filter.
Software I have written to test this circuit generates "00" for 1/4 of the signal period, "01" for 1/8 of the period, "10" for 1/8 of the period, "11" for 1/4 of the period, "10" for 1/8 of the period, and "01" for the final 1/8 of the period before repeating.
This timing has been enough to confirm operation of the circuit, but the waveform looks closer to a filtered sawtooth than a Sine.
I have control of the transition times (I'm not stuck with a fixed sample frequency), but I'm stuck working out the correct transition timings for a Sine wave. I guess the duration at "00" and "11" should be a little longer than 1/4 of the signal period, and the duration at "01" and "10" should be correspondingly shorter, but that's as far as I have gone.
Anyone able to assist -

with the correct correct transition times for this circuit; or for extra points..
with how to calculate the transistion times for any DAC resolution

Thanks in advance

This timing has been enough to confirm operation of the circuit, but the waveform looks closer to a filtered sawtooth than a Sine. But a correctly filtered sawtooth would be a sine!

you say you're not stuck with fixed sample frequency, so how high can you go, compared to the frequency of the sine?

@MarcusMüller - The signaling frequency is 1200 / 2100 Hz, I can generate the transitions to sub-microsecond accuracy, so there is plenty of precision to set the transitions at whatever time I need.

@MarcusMüller - Point taken - A correctly filtered sawtooth would be a sine :-) , Lets say a filter letting through the second harmonic as well.

After a nights rest I came up with this solution.
My DAC levels are equally spaced, and correspond to levels +1, +$\frac{1}{3}$, -$\frac{1}{3}$, and -1. I calculated the points where the sine wave crosses the middle between these points and used that as the transistion time.
So, the middle between +1 and +$\frac{1}{3}$ is +$\frac{2}{3}$. sin-1 ( $\frac{2}{3}$ ) = 0.73 rad = 0.116 full cycles. This is slightly less than the 0.125 ($\frac{1}{8}$) that I guessed initially.
So, I set my times for "00" and "11" states to last 0.268 of the cycle, and the "01", "10", "10", and "01" states to each last for 0.116 of the cycle.
I'm still not certain this is a perfect solution. I guess a "best" solution would minimise the integrated error between the generated waveform and the sine wave.  Nevertheless it does fit my intuition that the "00" and "11" states need to be a little longer than $\frac{1}{4}$, and the other states a little shorter than $\frac{1}{8}$ of a cycle.
I'd still be interested if anyone has a better solution - minimising the total error between the transmitted waveform and the sine wave seems like the way to go.


The signaling frequency is 1200 / 2100 Hz, I can generate the transitions to sub-microsecond accuracy, so there is plenty of precision to set the transitions at whatever time I need.

What you're telling us there is that you have a 2 bit DAC, but you can oversample by a factor of several hundreds – so do that. In a first step, convert your 2.1 kHz of sine values to samples than twice that frequency, than map them (i.e., quantize them) to PWM duty cycles, and use your converter to produce a PWM.
The reconstruction filter will take care of the harmonics of the PWM frequency, and you get a smooth output.
Next step would probably be dithering the values before quantizing them for PWM, and since your DAC seems to be fast enough, maybe replace the PWM with a randomized-position PDM, if that yields noise in a spectral shape which is better for your application.

I can precisely time the transitions, but can't generate a PWM.
I'm using a hardware up/down count/compare unit with two comparison thresholds. (AMD 6442 EPWM - https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/AM6442/datasheet#GUID-9E589AE5-8FB4-40FB-BF11-7D68ACECE1D3/TITLE-SPRSP56INT_SPRS932_CH06_00027 )
I set the different output DAC values as the counter passes the A and B comparators. I set the timing of the transitions by setting the A and B thresolds (with minimal computing overhead). Generating a PWM would require a lot more processing(with 8 channels operating simultaneously).

that is literally called a "PWM unit", and adjusting the threshold of an up or down counter compare unit is literally how any microcontroller generates PWM. Computational load is basically nonexistent, if you compute your sine wave to have the right amplitude within the resolution of the counter variable; a calculational effort which you have to do, anyways, if you want to do more than a square wave. at a couple kilohertz, this isn't even going to use a significant amount of your CPU time. There's typically DMA that can be used to automatically load the next value from memory to the …

… threshold register, so that all your firmware has to do is precompute a few values, often into one of two buffers, and you get an interrupt when the DMA engine has read half the buffer its currently processing, so you can then precompute the values in the other and go back to sleep.ö
